# JQuery: почему jquery не работает после обновления страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, python, jquery, flask

После нажатия на кнопку Scrape запускается подпроцесс. Также отображается сообщение о том, что подпроцесс работает и кнопка становится неактивной. Но если перезагрузить страницу, то надпись исчезнет и на кнопку снова можно нажать. Как сделать, чтобы на протяжении выполнения подпроцесса отображалось сообщение и кнопка была неактивной?

кнопка:

```js
<button id="scrape" class="btn btn-success mr-2">Scrape</button>

$('#scrape').on('click', () => {
    $('#scrape').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#status').text('Scraper is working...')
    $.post('/wellness', {'specialty': specialty, 'state': state, 'city': city, 'email': email}, (res) => {
      $('#scrape').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('#status').text('') 
      $(location).attr('href', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/wellness')
    });
  });
```

flask:

@app.route('/<page_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page(page_id):
file_py = f"{page_id}.py"

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    process = subprocess.Popen('python spiders/' + file_py, shell = True)
    process.wait()
```

Comment: Сохраняйте статус кнопки в cache

Comment: Как это сделать? Можете какой-то пример скинуть?